# DatePicker changes to NaN when attempting to change year in IE11

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

If you try to manually change the year value in the input field instead of using the popup the datepicker changes the value to "NaN/NaN/NaN".  This only seems to happen in IE11.  Works fine in Chrome.

Comment: This is happening for me on your [demo page.](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

I was having IE 11 / 10 issues with date and it was the intl polyfill

```
// Run `npm install --save intl`.
import 'intl';  
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js';
```

Comment: I tried adding intl, but still am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The described behavior is a known issue, which should be resolved in the latest release of @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs package.

Could you verify that the latest versions of the `@progress` packages are installed?

[The DateInput Overview demo](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/dateinput/) seems to work just fine:

https://screencast.com/t/rURuHEc9h5

**EDIT**

The DatePicker component experience the same issue in IE11 just like the DateInput. The issue is logged in public Kendo-Angular repo:

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/538

Subscribe for the issue to be notified once it is fixed.

Comment: I ran npm install --save @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs, but it still is not working.  The demo on your site does appear to be working now.

Comment: How do I tell what version of kendo-angular-dateinputs I have?

Comment: run `npm ls @progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs` in the terminal. It should be  `1.0.1`.

Comment: After a second review of your questions, I noticed that you are mentioning DatePicker, which unfortunately still has the same issue. It is logged here - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/538 and will be fixed with high priority.

Comment: Looks like I didn't have 1.0.1 either.  I will subscribe to the issue above and get the latest version.  Thank you!